# Error inflating class fragment in Android popular movies app

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

After i made some changes in an AsynTask i get this error when running the app:
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.popularmovies/com.example.android.popularmovies.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

This is the activity_main.xml file.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/fragment"
      android:name="com.example.android.popularmovies.MainActivityFragment"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And this is the MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.android.popularmovies;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure try the following:
Add

```
tools:context= ".MainActivity"
```

or Can you put `<fragment>` inside a `<FrameLayout>`.
Clean the code once.